# what is main difference in a .pyi file and .py file?

Tags: python

i see that some packages in python use this .pyi files.
Can i use this extension while building a project, and this has any useful application that can't be done with .py files?

Comment: this question is more about the meaning, i'm looking for what exactly i can do with .pyi that cant be done with .py

Comment: That kind of question doesn't really seem to be in-line with what StackOverflow is for. This is just a site for getting help with your own code that you've already written, not necessarily asking general/hypothetical/open-ended questions and such. Maybe look at the [tour], the [ask] page and this [help/on-topic] topic and see if you can rephrase your question in a way that fits the site's guidelines, if you don't end up getting a satisfactory answer.